# superfish dropdown disappears on hover

Tags: drop-down-menu, superfish

Let me preface this by saying that I'm not exactly a developer - Working on updating a nonprofit website using Dreamweaver (what a delight!).

I'm having issues with a Superfish dropdown in Internet Explorer. Though the dropdown does appear on top of the other elements on the page (slideshow, photos, etc), the dropdown menu closes when I hover over a menu item that's on top of another page element.  Not sure how else to explain it. Any suggestions?

**CSS**

```
    @charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,label,input,p,blockquote,table,tr,th,td,embed,object,button{margin:0;padding:0;}

body{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px; line-height:18px; background: #EBEBEB;}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:0px;
    color:#639ec8;
}

a:hover{color:#7f8675;}

img{text-decoration:none; border:0px;}

li{
    text-decoration:none;
        margin-left: 15px;
}

ul{text-decoration:none;
}


.list ul li{    
    margin-left: 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.newtab{
text-align:left;
background:#CCCCCC;
width:100%;
}

.newtab td{
padding:2px;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:12px;
}

.newtab th{
padding-left:2px;
vertical-align:top;
background-color:#F3F3F3;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
}

#main_wrapper{  
    float:left; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    padding:0px; 
    width:100%; 
}

#main{
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:920px;
}

#mainInner{
    width:920px; 
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    background:#ffffff;
}

#top_portion_left{
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    margin: 15px 0px 15px 10px
}

#top_portion_right{
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    height:100px;
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 00px
}

#top_portion_right p{
    text-align:right;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#757575;
}

#top_portion h1{
    float:left;
    margin:23px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#banner{
    width:900px;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#banner ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#banner h2{
    color:#ee8b3a;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.link a{
    background:url(../images/learnmore.png) no-repeat;
    width:143px;
    height:24px;
    color:#a34f0a;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-indent:15px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0;
}

.link a:hover{
    background:url(../images/learnmore.png) no-repeat;
    width:143px;
    height:24px;
    color:#7f8675;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-indent:15px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width:900px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddede;
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#homeinner{
    width:900px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddede;
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#homeinner a{
    color:#639ec8;
    font-size:18px;
    width:250px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#homeinner a:hover{
    color:#7f8675;
    font-size:18px;
    width:250px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#homeinner ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.welcom_head{
    color: #639ec8;
    font-size:18px;
        text-align:left;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    text-transforM: uppercase;
}

.welcom_head a{
    color: #639ec8;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.welcom_head a:hover{
    color: #7f8675;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.email{
/*  background:url(../images/email_txt.png) no-repeat; */
    width:205px;
    height:25px;
    border:0px;
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 15px;
}

.inner_right_head{
    color:#ee8b3a;
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-bottom:10px;

}

#middle{
    width:900px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dddede;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.middle_top{
    width:280px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
}

.middle_top ul, li{
    list-style: none;
}

.middle_bottom{
    width:210px;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.middle_bottom ul, li{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
}

.middle_part{
    width:195px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/middle_sprt.png) right no-repeat;
    padding:20px 20px 20px 0px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.middle_part h4{
    color:#577AA6;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.middle_part p{
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px  0px 10px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    width:185px;
}

.middle_part a{
    color:#577AA6;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:150px;
    height:24px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.middle_part a:hover{
    color:#7f8675;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:115px;
    height:24px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.middle_part1{

    width:185px;
    float:right;
    padding:25px 10px 20px 10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.middle_part1 h4{
    color:#577AA6;
    font-size:21px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.middle_part1 p{

    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px  0px 10px 0px;
    text-align:left;
    width:185px;
}

.middle_part1 a{
    color:#ee8b31;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:150px;
    height:28px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.middle_part1 a:hover{
    color:#7f8675;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:150px;
    height:28px;
    padding:4px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#bottom_portion{
    width:900px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

#bottom_portion ul{
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:910px;
}

#bottom_portion li{
    float:left;
}

#bottom_portion li img{
    float:left;
}


#footer{
    width:900px;
    background:#ffffff;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin:0px 10px 20px 10px;
}

#footer p{
    color:#616161;
    font-size:10px;
    width:900px;
    line-height: 10px;
}

#footer p a{
    color:#ee8b3a;
    font-size:11px;
}

#footer ul{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
}

#footer ul li{
    float:left;
    color:#616161
}

#footer ul li a{
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
}

#footer ul li a:hover{
    color:#181717;
    font-size:12px;
}

.search{
    background:url(../images/search_bg.png) no-repeat;
    width:196px;
    height:32px;
    border:0px;
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:8px 0px 0px 15px;
    margin:7px 0px 0px 10px;
    float:right;
}

.sidebar{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    padding:20px 0px 20px 10px;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#616161;
    font-size:10px;
}

.side_menu{
    width:225px;
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.side_menu ul{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.side_menu ul li{
    float:left;
    width:200px;    
}

.side_menu a{
    color:#666;
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    width:225px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.side_menu a:hover{

    color:#7f8675;
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    width:225px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.inner_portion_left{
    width:610px;
    float:right;
    padding:20px 20px 25px 0px;
    text-align:justify;
    color:#616161;
    font-size:12px;
}

.welcomecontent

{
    float:left;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    width:600px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    color: #757575;
    line-height:22px;
}

.middlecontent_left

    {
        float:left;
        margin:16px 0 0 0;
        padding:0 20px 15px 0px;
        width:260px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:13px;
        color: #757575;
        line-height:23px;
        text-align:justify;
    }

.middlecontent_left b

    {
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:13px;
        color: #ee8b3a;
        text-align:justify;
    }

.middlecontent_right

    {
        float:left;
        margin:16px 0 0 0;
        padding:0 0px 15px 20px;
        width:260px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:13px;
        color: #757575;
        line-height:23px;
        text-align:justify;
    }

.middlecontent_right b

    {
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:13px;
        color: #ee8b3a;
        text-align:justify;
    }

.usefullinks{
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.usefullinks li{
    width:500px;
    background:url(../images/arrow.jpg) left no-repeat;
    padding-left:30px;
    line-height:23px;

}

.usefullinks li a{

    color:#585858;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:20px;



}

.usefullinks li a:hover{

    color:#ee8b3a;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:20px;

}

.contactus{

    float:left;
    width:300px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size:13px;
    color: #727272;
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:20px;
}

.contactus em{

    font-weight:bold;

}

.inner_portion_left ul#blog{

    width:580px;
    margin:3px 0 0 0;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
}

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li{

    width:580px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0 0 25px 0;
    float:left;
}

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li h2{

    width:580px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font:bold 16px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#777;
}

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li p.blogcontent

    {

        float:left;
        margin:9px 0 0 0;
        padding:0px;
        width:580px;
        text-align: justify

    }

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li p.blogcontent a

    {

        color: #ee8b3a;
        text-decoration: underline;

    }

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li p.blogcontent a:hover

    {

        color: #ee8b3a;
        text-decoration: none;

    }

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li p.blogcontent span

    {

        color: #ee8b3a;
        font-weight:bold;

    }

.inner_portion_left ul#blog li p.blogimage

    {

        float:left;
        margin:9px 0 0 0;
        padding:0px;
        width:525px;

    }



.pfContent {

    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
    border: 0px dotted #999999;

}

.pfImg {

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin:0px 0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.pfText {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    width: 350px;
    float: right;

}

.pfText p{

    padding: 0px;
    margin: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#616161;
    width:295px;
    float:left;
}

.pfText h1 {

    font-size:18px;
    color: #ee8b3a;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    float:left;
    text-align: left;

}

.pfText em{

    font-size:17px;
    color: #616161;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float:left;
    width:295px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.pfText a{
    float:left;
    width:90px;
    height:31px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color: #ee8b3a;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:26px;
    margin-top:5px;

}

.pfText a:hover{
    color:#333;
}

/*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
#menublock{
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    float:left;
    background:#639ec8;
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}

.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sf-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

.sf-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
.sf-menu > li {
    float: left;
}
.sf-menu li:hover > ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.sf-menu a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.sf-menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.sf-menu {
    float: left;

}
.sf-menu ul {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    min-width: 12em; /* allow long menu items to determine submenu width */
    *width: 12em; /* no auto sub width for IE7, see white-space comment below */
}
.sf-menu a {
    padding: .75em 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    zoom: 1; /* IE7 */
}
.sf-menu a {
    color:#FFF;
}

.sf-menu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.sf-menu li {
    background:#639ec8;
    white-space: nowrap; /* no need for Supersubs plugin */
    *white-space: normal; /* ...unless you support IE7 (let it wrap) */
    -webkit-transition: background .2s;
    transition: background .2s;
}
.sf-menu ul li {
    background:#639ec8;
}
.sf-menu ul ul li {
    background: #9AAEDB;
}
.sf-menu li:hover,
.sf-menu li.sfHover {
    background: #CFDEFF;
    /* only transition out, not in */
    -webkit-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

/*** arrows (for all except IE7) **/
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul {
    padding-right: 2.5em;
    *padding-right: 1em; /* no CSS arrows for IE7 (lack pseudo-elements) */
}
/* styling for both css and generated arrows */
.sf-arrows .sf-with-ul:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1em;
    margin-top: -3px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    /* order of following 3 rules important for fallbacks to work */
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: #dFeEFF; /* edit this to suit design (no rgba in IE8) */
    border-top-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.sf-arrows > li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after,
.sf-arrows > li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after,
.sf-arrows > .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after {
    border-top-color: white; /* IE8 fallback colour */
}
/* styling for right-facing arrows */
.sf-arrows ul .sf-with-ul:after {
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: -3px;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-left-color: #dFeEFF; /* edit this to suit design (no rgba in IE8) */
    border-left-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
.sf-arrows ul li > .sf-with-ul:focus:after,
.sf-arrows ul li:hover > .sf-with-ul:after,
.sf-arrows ul .sfHover > .sf-with-ul:after {
    border-left-color: white;
}
```

Comment: We will need a link to the actual problem page or a jsfiddle that shows the problem.

Comment: The site's currently offline but hopefully this will show the problem. http://www.simpsonhousing.org/newsite/donate.html

Comment: The menu on that site seems to work fine in chrome. nothing disappears...